# Whilst iterating through a list check that every 3 consecutive elements follow a pattern

Tags: python

I have a list of elements that should have every 3 consecutive elements follow a pattern however some of the data is missing and I'd like to fill where there is missing data with `" "`.

For example for the list below I would like to check that every third element starting from the first contains the word `"start"`, and every third element starting from the second one contains `"/"` and finally every third element starting from the third  contains `":"`

So this:

`list = ["start1", "mid/1", "end:1", "start2", "end:2", "mid/3", "end:3"]`

Would become this:

`list = ["start1", "mid/1", "end:1", "start2", " ", "end:2", " ", "mid/3", "end:3"]`

I've managed to use the following code to print out each of every 3rd element and the step number but im struggling on actually inserting the `" "`

`data = ["start1", "mid/1", "end:1", "start2", "end:2", "mid/3", "end:3", "start4", "mid/4", "end:4", "start5", "end:5"]`

```
    for step, init_info in enumerate(data[:3:], 1):
        for elem, info in enumerate(data[step-1::3], 1):
            print(step, info)
```

This returns:

`(1, 'start1')
(1, 'start2')
(1, 'end:3')
(1, 'end:4')
(2, 'mid/1')
(2, 'end:2')
(2, 'start4')
(2, 'start5')
(3, 'end:1')
(3, 'mid/3')
(3, 'mid/4')
(3, 'end:5')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using a simple loop over your source-list and some checking:

```
l = ["start1", "mid/1", "end:1", "start2", "end:2", "mid/3", "end:3"]

# defines which position must hold what thing in it to be not substituted
d = {0:"start", 1:"/", 2:":"}

# target list    
k = [] 

# counts the insertions, to adjust dict lookup
inserted = 0

for idx,e in enumerate(l):
    must_be_in_else_substitute = d.get( (idx+inserted) % 3)
    if must_be_in_else_substitute in e:
        k.append(e)
    else:
        inserted+=1
        k.extend([" ",e])
print(k)
```

Output:

```
['start1', 'mid/1', 'end:1', 'start2', ' ', 'end:2', ' ', 'mid/3', 'end:3']
```

---

You could use a generator as @timgeb suggested, dunno how reusable that one is as most of the "rules" are kindof set. This does about the same as the code above, just more lazy:

```
l = ["start1", "mid/1", "end:1", "start2", "end:2", "mid/3", "end:3"]    

def insert_something_if_at_pos_not_in(rules,data,tbi=" "):
    """No idea how to docstring this in a sensible way - lets say 
    it does what the OP described :o)"""
    inserted=0
    rule_max = max(rules.keys())+1
    for idx,e in enumerate(data):
        must_be_in = rules.get( (idx+inserted) % rule_max)
        if must_be_in in e:
            yield e
        else:
            yield " "
            yield e

print(    list(insert_something_if_at_pos_not_in({0:"start", 1:"/", 2:":"},l) ))
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing a regex pattern into the dictionary to not be substituted?

Answer (score -1):

the [.get()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method allow You to put a default value if non is inserted in it. But that's a method for dictionaries.
try to pair it with .append for creating Your list